# How to pass TDE certification in sql server 2012

Tags: sql-server

I have the master database and certification keys records for one of my database my question is how I can restore TDE database without password? is it possible to pass it away I can copy all certification row from my backup master database.

Answer (score 0):

You have to backup the server certificate and the private key to file, and use them to recreate the certificate on the target server.

There is a step-by-step guide on the MS Technet on moving TDE protected databases:

http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff773063.aspx

Comment: As I've already mentioned, I don't have any passwords and keys I've just made a backup of "Data" folder. this way shows at this site you have to know key or password if you want to move certification to another server. In fact I have all files but I don't have any key or password so I doesn't work for me.

Comment: So, it's not a database backup of master, but rather a copy of master.mdf? You could try install a new instance and replace it's master with your copy. Sincerely, I doubt it would work, but I have no other idea.

Comment: I did it and it wouldn't work. Is there any way to just move or copy from my old mater database to new one ?